# Locust load testing - change hatch rate from seconds to minutes?

Tags: python, load, performance-testing, locust

I'd like to simulate spikey traffic, so that for example:

- in the first 5 minutes there are only 50 users (instant hatch of 50 at time `T0`)
- then from 5th to 10th minute we have 100 users (instant hatch +50 at `T+5`)
- then 150 (instant hatch +50 at `T+10`)
- etc.

Is it possible to create an equal number of users, but instead of doing that every second change that to every xx minutes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such built in feature (https://github.com/locustio/locust/issues/1353 might solve this if it is ever implemented)

One way to do a workaround is to spawn all your users right away (using a spawn rate of something like 100/s), and have them sleep until it is time to run:

```
import time
start = time.time()

class User1(HttpUser):
    @task
    def mytask(self):
        # do actual task

class User2(HttpUser):
    @task
    def mytask(self):
        while time.time() - start < 300:
            time.sleep(1)
        # do actual task

class User3(HttpUser):
    @task
    def mytask(self):
        while time.time() - start < 600:
            time.sleep(1)
        # do actual task

...
```

You can probably do something clever and put it all in one class, but I'll leave that as an exercise :)

Answer (score 5):

## Locust 2.8.6 Update

Now you can benefit from using custom shapes. Read more at [Locust Documentation](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/custom-load-shape.html).

You should use the tick function and define the return tuple of your user limit and spawn rate.

Here is a code example:

```py
from locust import LoadTestShape


class SharpStepShape(LoadTestShape):
    increase_delay = 300  # 5 minutes for increase
    increase_size = 50  # number of extra users per increase

    def tick(self):
        run_time = self.get_run_time()
        step_number = int(run_time / self.increase_delay) + 1
        user_limit = int(step_number * self.increase_size)
        return user_limit, self.increase_size
```

Then just import this shape into your locustfile and it will use this shape for your load testing.

```py
from locust import User
from sharp_step_shape import SharpStepShape


class PerformanceUser(User):
    pass
```